# Selenium cant find element on element that exists in page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public class Sele
   {
        private IWebDriver driver;
        private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
        private string baseURL;
        private bool acceptNextAlert = true;

        public Sele( )
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver( );
            baseURL = "https://www.youtube.com/";
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder( );
        }

        internal void LikeYoutubeVidWithAcc( string username, string password, string url )
        {
            driver.Navigate( ).GoToUrl( baseURL + "/" );
            driver.FindElement( By.XPath( "(//button[@type='button'])[2]" ) ).Click( );
            driver.FindElement( By.Id( "Email" ) ).Clear( );
            driver.FindElement( By.Id( "Email" ) ).SendKeys( "UserName" );
            driver.FindElement( By.Id( "next" ) ).Click( );

            driver.FindElement( By.Id( "Passwd" ) ).Clear( );
            driver.FindElement( By.Id( "Passwd" ) ).SendKeys( "Password" );
            driver.FindElement( By.Id( "signIn" ) ).Click( );
            driver.Navigate( ).GoToUrl( url );
            driver.FindElement( By.XPath( "(//button[@type='button'])[25]" ) ).Click( );
        }
}
```

I'm having trouble signing in to youtube using selenium, for some reason it can't find the password element in the page.

the error occurs at this line:

```
 driver.FindElement( By.Id( "Passwd" ) ).Clear( );
```

Error message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Passwd"}
```

I know the element exists on the page, yet selenium can't find it.

Page source when the error occurs:

```
<div class="card signin-card      pre-shift         no-name shift-form">
  <div id="cc_iframe_parent"><iframe id="youtube" src="https://accounts.youtube.com/accounts/CheckConnection?pmpo=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com&amp;v=-951713550&amp;timestamp=1469398858532" style="visibility: hidden; width: 1px; height: 1px; position: absolute; top: -100px;"></iframe></div>
  <div class="circle-mask" style="background-image: none;">
  <canvas id="canvas" class="circle" width="96" height="96"></canvas>
  </div>
  <form novalidate="" method="post" action="https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password" id="gaia_loginform">
  <input name="Page" value="PasswordSeparationSignIn" type="hidden">
  <input name="GALX" value="bX35kb1ARtQ" type="hidden">
  <input name="gxf" value="AFoagUWY2FAFLKhmD2_-vufme-BJ1jfACg:1469398858433" type="hidden">
  <input name="continue" value="https://www.youtube.com/signin?next=%2F&amp;hl=en&amp;feature=sign_in_button&amp;app=desktop&amp;action_handle_signin=true" type="hidden">
  <input name="service" value="youtube" type="hidden">
  <input name="hl" value="en" type="hidden">
  <input id="profile-information" name="ProfileInformation" value="APMTqulOYcx8i4BIKa7QX8vzLf8nHVle5wmAmPaLqZqa7bjp6poGeUD2zvzYvR46xap0wdwr2kQaxUuteML1f-hTwb_VW4ZDLaD0cYYzVup4THWBRGWMWv0" type="hidden">
  <input id="_utf8" name="_utf8" value="☃" type="hidden">
  <input name="bgresponse" id="bgresponse" value="!DwylDC1CEBfic73NLmFEPmLuo0jLmEwCAAAAH1IAAAAFCgASXF5p4wpYu2Whl5kDy5GtZSOFmQEOdst3NYj0yd4fKBLZxl94_2g92h7yeFimnFaHcZosa1A6tveg3lkaz-HEnxsgWWDRAptp3hXbMHf10f_l5URE4mup4YdMKniavQDRHw1mYbNpaTFcVbTQhb2Fq8zAY89pRskujAVj_FVIMin3uw8U3Ncz0sjSkkSBbSi7TneLgUGXSI-GHNUS6uVJGKfqXUCSMkdDA2d71bq-oANdlKwxKOyCAAIkcNAwwuROjGY1wiWaMRofROyHO3PfRvpdwtKP0MfCUCvFU88cdyXKHt-xyJO76CR96U3E5loZGOFscMs8BCy2KpyjeyE6yGHVcSAMFI9NgQfT0Gv5E4687eD__44iyMRuyd4xUYcetZAL" type="hidden">
  <input id="pstMsg" name="pstMsg" value="1" type="hidden">
  <input id="dnConn" name="dnConn" value="" type="hidden">
  <input id="checkConnection" name="checkConnection" value="youtube:254:1" type="hidden">
  <input id="checkedDomains" name="checkedDomains" value="youtube" type="hidden">
  <div class="form-panel first valid" id="gaia_firstform">
  <div style="transition-delay: 0ms;" class="slide-out hide-form">
  <div class="input-wrapper focused">
  <div id="identifier-shown"></div>
  <span role="alert" class="error-msg" id="errormsg_0_Email"></span>
  </div>
<div style="display: none" id="identifier-captcha">
<input name="identifiertoken" id="identifier-token" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="identifiertoken_audio" id="identifier-token-audio" type="hidden">
<div class="audio-box">
  <div id="playIdentifierAudio"></div>
</div>
<div id="captcha-box" class="captcha-box">
  <div id="captcha-img" class="captcha-img" data-alt-text="Visual verification"></div>
  <span class="captcha-msg">
  Letters are not case-sensitive
  </span>
</div>
<label for="identifier-captcha-input" class="hidden-label"></label>
<input id="identifier-captcha-input" name="identifier-captcha-input" class="captcha" placeholder="Enter the letters above" title="Type the characters you see or numbers you hear" type="text">
</div>
<input id="next" name="signIn" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" value="Next" type="submit">
  <a class="need-help" href="https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Fnext%3D%252F%26hl%3Den%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26app%3Ddesktop%26action_handle_signin%3Dtrue&amp;service=youtube&amp;ignoreShadow=0&amp;hl=en">
  Need help?
  </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <a href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Fnext%3D%252F%26hl%3Den%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26app%3Ddesktop%26action_handle_signin%3Dtrue&amp;service=youtube&amp;hl=en" tabindex="-1">
  <img id="back-arrow" class="back-arrow shift-form" aria-label="Back" tabindex="0" alt="Back" src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/arrow_back_grey600_24dp.png">
  </a>
  <div class="form-panel second">
  <div style="transition-delay: 100ms;" class="slide-in">
  <div>
  <p style="display: none;" id="profile-name"></p>
  <span id="email-display">email123456@gmail.com</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <div id="password-shown"><div>
  <input name="Email" id="Email-hidden" spellcheck="false" class="hidden" value="" readonly="" autocomplete="off" type="email">
<label class="hidden-label" for="Passwd">Password</label>
<input id="Passwd" name="Passwd" placeholder="Password" class="" type="password">
  </div></div>
  </div>
<input id="signIn" name="signIn" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" value="Sign in" type="submit">
  <label class="remember">
  <input id="PersistentCookie" name="PersistentCookie" value="yes" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
  <span>
  Stay signed in
  </span>
  <div class="bubble-wrap" role="tooltip">
  <div class="bubble-pointer"></div>
  <div class="bubble">
  For your convenience, keep this checked. On shared devices, additional precautions are recommended.
  <a href="https://support.google.com/accounts/?p=securesignin&amp;hl=en" target="_blank">Learn more</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </label>
  <input name="rmShown" value="1" type="hidden">
  <a id="link-forgot-passwd" class="need-help" href="https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Fnext%3D%252F%26hl%3Den%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26app%3Ddesktop%26action_handle_signin%3Dtrue&amp;service=youtube&amp;checkedDomains=youtube&amp;checkConnection=youtube%3A254%3A1&amp;pstMsg=1&amp;Email=wageeh14032%40gmail.com&amp;ignoreShadow=0&amp;hl=en">
  Forgot password?
  </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <span id="inge" style="display: none" role="alert" class="error-msg">
  Sorry, Google doesn't recognize that email. <a href="https://accounts.google.com/SignUpWithoutGmail?service=youtube&amp;continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Fnext%3D%252F%26hl%3Den%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26app%3Ddesktop%26action_handle_signin%3Dtrue&amp;hl=en">Create an account</a> using that address?
  </span>
  <span id="timeoutError" style="display: none" role="alert" class="error-msg">
  Something went wrong. Check your connection and try again.
  </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using a `WebDriverWait` or using the implicit timeout.

Comment: you basically need to wait after clicking next and before entering the password. Without the wait, WebDriver is trying to find the element where the new page is not actually loaded up yet. Either use explicit Thread.Sleep or WebDriverWait until the element shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); //you can change 10 seconds to whatever it suits you the best.
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Passwd")));
```